# How to add some empty line when using `json.dumps` on Python 3?

Tags: python, json

For example, I have a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'Name': 'Jone', 'Job': 'Boss', 'From': 'England', (and many many more...)}
```

As you can see, this dictionary is very very long. so I can display it in my code like this:

```
 a = {'Name': 'Jone',
      'Job': 'Boss',
      'From': 'England',
      (and many many more...)}
```

But when I using `json.dumps` to save this dictionary in a file, it will display as one line. So it's hard to check and edit.

So how can I save a dictionary use json in more line, and load that? use `str.split` when load and dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem! `json.dumps` has some built in options to help out.

Try doing it like this...

```
string = json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

And write your new string to the file. :)

Comment: @KevinGuan No problem Kevin! Please remember to mark one of our answers as correct if they helped you. We'd appreciate it, and it'll help other users who have this issue in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Yes I will :). But seems like must 7 minutes later.

Answer (score 1):

The API is that you specify the indent you would like for each line:

```
import json

print(json.dumps(dict(a=1, b=2), indent='    '))

{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

Comment: All good with me :-) So long as you got the answer you needed. I actually ran into the same thing yesterday myself.